# how to setup replication instance in on premises postgres for master database in AWS RDS postgres?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have a requirement of checking whether the exact copy of master database from AWS RDS can be created in on premises or not..
I have already established the connectivity between on prem and aws. Also checked the data migration using pg dump. But i am not getting how to create the replica without using DMS. Due to some security purpose we are not supposed to use DMS. So is there any other way out to implement thi ?
Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Amazon RDS does not offer the capability to create a Read Replica outside of AWS. You would need to use an external tool (such as AWS DMS) to copy the data. What is your _actual_ goal? That is, _what_ are you wanting to achieve, rather than _how_ to achieve it? Is there simply a desire to have an offsite backup in case of failure? Have you considered using multiple AZs and Regions instead?

Comment: yes @JohnRotenstein, the idea is to keep the backup in on premises for the purpose of disaster recovery

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your goal is disaster recovery.

Amazon RDS offers a few options for this:

**Amazon RDS Snapshots** are a backup of the database, stored in a region. If your database is in an **Availability Zone** that fails, the snapshot can be restored as a new database in another AZ. All AZs are physically separate data centers, much like your own data center is physically separate from an AWS data center.

Snapshots can also be **copied to other Regions**, which would guarantee a separation distance between data centers.

**Multi-AZ Amazon RDS Databases** keep a second copy of the data in another AZ and can switch-over to the alternate AZ without losing any data. This is faster than restoring a snapshot, but costs twice as much since two separate database servers are deployed.

These options would be easier to manage than replicating your data to an on-premises system. A Multi-AZ will automatically start the secondary instance, so your app can continue operating with only a short delay and no data loss. This is much better than you could offer if you fail-over to an on-premises system.